# Custom service extension for .Net Core web app not mapping the same

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to write the ServiceCollection extension below. What's weird is that when trying to pass `section` to the `services.Configure()` method, it says it can't be converted from `IConfigurationSection` to `Action<EsiConfig>`.

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddEsi(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection section)
{
    services.Configure<EsiConfig>(section);
    services.AddScoped<IEsiClient, EsiClient>();

    return services;
}
```

What's weird about that is this code in Startup.cs is identical:

```cs
services.Configure<EsiConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ESIConfig"));
services.AddScoped<IEsiClient, EsiClient>();

// Implementation of the ServiceCollection extension
services.AddEsi(Configuration.GetSection("ESIConfig"));
```

That first line works perfectly fine, and when you hover over GetSection, it returns an ICollectionSection that is passed into the same exact method (`Config()`) that accepts the same exact property type of `Action<EsiConfig>`.

Not sure what I am missing at all and am really confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the reference for `services.Configure<EsiConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ESIConfig"));` and `services.Configure<EsiConfig>(section);` and make sure you used `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions`.

Here is a working project [ConfigurationPro](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/ConfigurationPro/Extension/ConfigurationExtension.cs)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Figured it was something like this, but I had no clue which package could possibly be missing. Hadn't used this one before so was unaware of it.

Comment: Thank you I had the same exact problem and this resolved it!